# Display only the buffer coding systems but not keyboard or terminal coding system in mode line

Tags: mode-line, character-encoding

By default, in terminal, emacs's `mode-line-mule-info` displays:

1. buffer coding systems
2. keyboard coding systems
3. terminal coding systems
4. EOF indicator

Example:

```
-UUU:%%--F1  *GNU Emacs*    All L1     (Fundamental) ---------------------------
```

I want just the buffer coding systems, but not the keyboard or terminal coding systems like:

```
-U:%%--F1  *GNU Emacs*    All L1     (Fundamental) -----------------------------
```

Is there a way to turn them off?

Comment: I found mode-line-mule-info consists of `%z` and mode-line-eol-desc, but knows nothing further.

Comment: To me it looks like this behavior is 'hard-coded' in the C code. Therefore, I guess you can better pose this question in the [Emacs help mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/help-gnu-emacs) (or notify them about your question here)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last of the three mule-info characters corresponds to the buffer coding system in Emacs 28.1.
So I give a solution for that case.

It is right that the replacement for `"%z"` is hard-coded in function `decode_mode_spec` of `xdisp.c`.

In the following code we replace `"%z"` by an expression that is to be evaluated.
The expression evaluates the mode line format string `"%z"` and returns just the one-character substring at the end of it.

```el
  (defconst mode-line-buffer-coding-info (or
                      ;; avoid repeated setting:
                      (and (boundp 'mode-line-buffer-coding-info)
                           mode-line-buffer-coding-info)
                      ;; actual value:
                      (assoc-string "%z" mode-line-mule-info)))

  (setf (car (member "%z" (default-value 'mode-line-mule-info))) '(:eval (substring (format-mode-line mode-line-buffer-coding-info) -1 nil)))
```

You can put this code into your init file.

---

About the order of the coding system indicators:

The source code of `decode_mode_spec` in [`xdisp.c`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/master/src/xdisp.c) for processing the `'z'` format letter is:

```c
    case 'z':
      /* coding-system (not including end-of-line format) */
    case 'Z':
      /* coding-system (including end-of-line type) */
      {
    bool eol_flag = (c == 'Z');
    char *p = decode_mode_spec_buf;

    if (! FRAME_WINDOW_P (f))
      {
        /* No need to mention EOL here--the terminal never needs
           to do EOL conversion.  */
        p = decode_mode_spec_coding (CODING_ID_NAME
                     (FRAME_KEYBOARD_CODING (f)->id),
                     p, false);
        p = decode_mode_spec_coding (CODING_ID_NAME
                     (FRAME_TERMINAL_CODING (f)->id),
                     p, false);
      }
    p = decode_mode_spec_coding (BVAR (b, buffer_file_coding_system),
                     p, eol_flag);
```

where `decode_mode_spec_coding` takes the char buffer pointer `p`, adds the char(s) for the coding system and returns the incremented pointer.

As we see, at first it processes the keyboard coding then the terminal coding and at last the buffer encoding.

Furthermore: From the [Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mode-Line.html#:%7E:text=On%20a%20text%20terminal):

> On a text terminal, cs is preceded by two additional characters that describe the coding systems for keyboard input and terminal output. Furthermore, if you are using an input method, cs is **preceded** by a string that identifies the input method (see Input Methods).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But isn't it the first of the mule-info characters corresponds to the buffer coding system?

Comment: @Alaneuler I added a section on the order of the coding system indicators.